# Push message to all online users using Flask, WITHOUT creating threads for each users

Tags: python, flask, chat

Suppose ther is a chat group.
Is there a way to append new messages sent by any member of a particular group to the html page of all the online users in that group using FLASK.

WITHOUT: creating a thread for each users and monitoring for latest updates in the chats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example, with a very minimal code. If you are interested then you can explore more and do the experiments.

Firstly, you need the Flask-SocketIO module, run the below command to install it.

```
pip install flask-socketio
```

With this example, the project directory will be something like below:

```
ProjectDirectory
|
|-> templates
|   |
|   |-> index.html
|
|-> app.py
```

**app.py**

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'randomSecretKEy@123'
socket = SocketIO(app)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@socket.on('message')
def message(data):
    print(data)
    emit('receive_message', data, broadcast=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socket.run(app)
```

**index.html**

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js" integrity="sha256-yr4fRk/GU1ehYJPAs8P4JlTgu0Hdsp4ZKrx8bDEDC3I=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var socket = io();
    socket.on('connect', function() {
        console.log('Connected to server');
    });
    socket.on('receive_message', function(msg) {
        console.log('Received message: ', msg)
    })
    function sendMessage() {
        msg = $('#message').val()
        socket.emit('message', msg)
    }
</script>
<input type="text" id="message"><button onclick="sendMessage()">Send</button>
```

Run the Flask app, open two browser tabs, with web developer tools opened side by side. AS soon as you open, you will see that `Connected to server` message has been logged. Now, type some message and hit the send button, in one tab, and you will see that, the message has been received in another tab's console.

I hope you get a direction with this and it is helpful for you.

---

**Note:** Again, I am telling this is a very basic example. Off course, you can add more logic and functionality, and make it more like a chatting app, but it will be out of the scope of this question. So, I will leave it to you and your imagination, to which extent you can learn and take this ahead. You can read about the module's documentation [here](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: This was really helpful. But is there a way by which i can filter the emit message on the server side itself like based on things like which message gets emited to whom ?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to emit to a particular user also, using `room`s.

Comment: It really helped. Thanks a lot.